# NUXT JS insert Array inside Array and display forEach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

Good afternoon everyone!

I'm stuck since 3 days searching answers in forums and here also, and i can't solve it.. Maybe you can help about this problem:

In javascript is easier, but in NUXT we can't insert Javascript where we wan't..

In the component page:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
 
    data() {
      return {
       players: [],
    };
    },



    created() {
      let instance =this;


      for (let i=1; i <= 21; i++) {
        axios
          .get(`https://api.test/player/${i}`)
          .then((response) => {
            let player= {
              name: response.data.name,
              url: response.data.url,
              
            };
            
              instance.players.push(player);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
  },



};
</script>
```

This url is a test. But it's return an array about skills of player 1. I already display the skills of this player.

But i need to display the  forEach players, their skills (40 players).

**EDIT:**
**thanks for your comments.
But now it's filled the Array in the wrong order, and i don't know where to put the Async await? i suppose is this error**

Comment: NuxtJS is only a framework built on top of JS. It is still 100% JavaScript and there should be no differences. The problem with the current code is very likely a missing `async/await` keyword somewhere. Very likely you need a `Promises.all()` in your array. Take a look at this tutorial and see if things clear up: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-promise-all/

Comment: So what wrote down Nadav is correct no?    --- async fetch() {
    await this.fillArray();
  }, 
---

Answer (score 0):

Be aware forEach not support async methods, you have to use regular for or while

```
data() {
    return {
      ArraySkills: [],
    };
  },
  async fetch() {
    await this.fillArray();
  },
  methods: {
    async fillArray() {
      let id = 1;
      while (id < 41) {
        id++;
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.test/player/${id}`);
        const ArraySkill = response.json();
        this.ArraySkills.push(ArraySkill);
      }
    },
  },
```